# A book that focuses on optimization methods for image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I am an image processing engineer. I my work I often find that there are many aspects for my code to be improved. Who can recommend a book which focuses on optimization methods for image processing? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: This question is usually not a good fit for the Q&A format, so I'm tempted to close it. However, if you get good responses I will make it a wiki. I'll give it some time.

Comment: I've edited you question to fix some grammatical minutia. Now you should make sure people know what to answer. Some specific examples will help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "optimization" exactly ? Do you mean performance optimization ?

Comment: Yes,Its better for the book to focus on performance optimization. But, any book focuses on other optimization aspects will be suitable too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on yor actual focus.
For mathematical models and algorithms, I've seen people using this book: [The Handbook of Mathematical Models in Computer Vision](http://vision.mas.ecp.fr/paragios-chen-faugeras/).

If the focus is more on Computer Vision, I've found these books useful too (including mathematical background):

- [Richard Szeliski's recent book](http://szeliski.org/Book/) (from Microsoft Research)
- or [Computer Vision, a modern approach (2nd ed.).](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Computer_vision.html?id=a3-TQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) This book has many small assignements at the end of each chapter that you can use to improve your work step-by-step.